# Does expect(...).toBe resolve promises or do I need to wait for them?

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

Protractor testing is hard and confusing (at least for me).

I have the following

```
`SomeTestFile.spec.ts`
describe('A test: ', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      ....
    }

    it ('Should validate a label', async() => {
      await helper.validateALabel(label);
    }   

    ....
}
```

Then in the helper class:

```
helper.ts
export class Helper {
  ....

  public validateLabel(label: String): Promise<void> {
    expect(label).toBe('This is the string of the label');
  }

  ....
}
```

So the question is do I need to await the `expect(label).toBe(...)`?

Should it be

```
await expect(label).toBe(...)
```

OR is this just fine (and if so why do I keep getting Unandled Promise Rejection Warnings)?

```
expect(label).toBe(...)
```

Comment: It is recommended to use `await` for expect statements

Comment: You can await your promise and use expect without await. If you use expect on a promise then `toBe` arg would have to be the promise you're comparing to

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't.

You have to await your promise and compare the result.

```
// example promise function
const validateALabel = (label) => new Promise(r => r(true))

it ('validates a label', async () => {
  const valid = await validateALabel(label)

  expect(valid).toBeTruthy()
})
```

In you case it seems you are defining the wrong return type here:

```
public validateLabel(label: String): Promise<void> {
  expect(label).toBe('This is the string of the label');
}
```

This actually doesn't return a `Promise<void>`, but just `void`, so you don't need async/await at all

Comment: Right, so IntelliJ tells me that .toBe(..) returns a Promise<void>. Yet the interface defines it as if it returns a boolean (with the documentation specifying a return value of {}).   


See here: https://imgur.com/a/TNcXayB


And then secondly, maybe this is bad practice and why it has happened to me a few times, I have used expect in a helper class (so not in the 'it..' block but in another file) and any verification has failed to process (so things that should fail simply don't).

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```js
test('resolves to lemon', async () => {
  await expect(Promise.resolve('lemon')).resolves.toBe('lemon');
});
```

From https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#resolves

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to use expects in the step definitions. You can resolve the value from the helper class and in your step definitions you can make some assertions and make the test step pass or fail.

```
`SomeTestFile.spec.ts`
describe('A test: ', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      ....
    }

    it ('Should validate a label', async() => {
      await expect(helper.validateALabel(label)).toBe('This is the string of the label');
    }   

    ....
    }
```

helper.ts

```
export class Helper {
  ....
 function validateLabel(label) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return resolve('This is the string of the label');
    })
 }

  ....
}
```